# Why isn't dot-assignment updating multiple arrays?

Tags: arrays, julia

I want to assign some computation into a pair of arrays, with the top portion going into array `x`, and the bottom portion going into `y`.  I attempted the following, but neither `x` nor `y` were updated:

```
x = zeros(2)
y = zeros(3)
[x;y] .= [1.2, 4.5, 2.3, 4.5, 5.6]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general<sup>1</sup>, the `.=` operator just assigns into whatever the *result* of the left hand side evaluates to — and in this case the result is a *brand new array* with the contents of `x` and `y` vertically concatenated.  You can see that `[x; y]` creates a new array decoupled from `x` and `y` by just trying it by itself:

```
x = zeros(2)
y = zeros(3)
r = [x;y]
r[1] = 1

julia> r
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0

julia> x
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0
 0.0

julia> y
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0

julia> r .= [1.2, 4.5, 2.3, 4.5, 5.6] # just changes `r`, not `x` or `y`
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.2
 4.5
 2.3
 4.5
 5.6

julia> all(iszero, x) && all(iszero, y)
true
```

Now, you can update `x` and `y` if they're put into a special "lazy" container from [LazyArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/LazyArrays.jl) that emulates a concatenation operation:

```
julia> using LazyArrays

julia> ApplyArray(vcat, x, y) .= [1.2, 4.5, 2.3, 4.5, 5.6]
5-element ApplyArray{Float64,1,typeof(vcat),Tuple{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}}}:
 1.2
 4.5
 2.3
 4.5
 5.6

julia> x
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.2
 4.5

julia> y
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.3
 4.5
 5.6
```

---

<sup>1</sup> There's one important exception to this general rule: we support indexed assignment with multiple selected indices in combination with `.=` to update the original array.  In other words, the syntax `y[1:2] .= [3.4, 5.6]` will indeed update the first two elements of `y`, even though `y[1:2]` elsewhere will allocate a brand new 2-element array decoupled from `y`. In other words, when you use indexing on the left-hand side of `.=`, it automatically uses a [`view`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.view) when necessary.

Comment: See this discourse thread for a bit more information about how you can see what Julia is doing by asking it! https://discourse.julialang.org/t/dot-assignment-what-is-going-on-here/2579